# what should I use instead of readableStream.push('')

Tags: node.js, stream

I am trying to implement the `._read` function of a readable stream, a problem happens when `._read` is called and there isn't data, the documentation says that I can `push('')` until more data comes, and I should only `return false` when the stream will never have more data.
https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_read_size_1

But it also says that if I need to do that then something is terribly wrong with my design.
https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_stream_push

But I can't find an alternative to that.

code:

```
    var http = require('http');
    var https = require('https');
    var Readable = require('stream').Readable;
    var router = require('express').Router();
    var buffer = [];

    router.post('/', function(clientRequest, clientResponse) {
        var delayedMSStream = new Readable;
        delayedMSStream._read = function() {
            var a=buffer.shift();
            if(typeof a === 'undefined'){
                this.push('');
                return true;
            }
            else {
                this.push(a);
                if(a===null) {
                    return false;
                }
                return true;
            }
        };
        //I need to get a url from example.com
        https.request({hostname:'example.com'}, function(exampleResponse){
            data='';
            exampleResponse.on('data',function(chunk){data+=chunk});
            exampleResponse.on('end',function(){
                var MSRequestOptions = {hostname: data, method: 'POST'};
                var MSRequest = https.request(MSRequestOptions, function(MSResponse){
                    MSResponse.on('end', function () {
                            console.log("MSResponse.on(end)");//>>>
                    });//end MSResponse.on(end)
                }); //end MSRequest
                delayedMSStream.pipe(MSRequest);
            });
        });

        clientRequest.on('data', function (chunk) {
            buffer.push(chunk);
        });

        clientRequest.on('end', function () {//when done streaming audio
            buffer.push(null);
        }); 
    });//end router.post('/')
```

explanation:
client sends a POST request streaming audio to my server, my server requests a url from `example.com`, when `example.com` responds with the url, my server streams the audio to it.

What's a smarter way to do it?

Comment: What is `buffer`? Where do you get that from?

Comment: clientRequest.on('data',function(chunk){
buffer.push(chunk);
});
it's in the code ^

Comment: No, I don't see it - you get a `chunk` and push it to a _buffer_. But I don't see where you've defined the buffer.

Comment: oh i'm sorry, I misunderstood your comment, just fixed it, `var buffer=[];`

Comment: In that case, I think you might have misread the "push returns false" part of the doc. It's `let result = this.push(chunk);` in your _read function. If result is false, stream should stop sending data for a while (means, the other end can't receive more data). But it's an internal method/check, only for old streams, not in streams2.

Comment: so what should I do for streams2?

Comment: Well in your case, it's not so much about streams2, as for modularity. Writing up an answer for ya ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99624/discussion-between-zlatko-and-bubakazouba).

Answer (score 1):

So if I undertstand the code correctly, you:

- receive a request,
- make your own request to a remote endpoint and fetch a URL
- make a new request to that URL and pipe that to original response.

There are ways to do this other then yours, and even your way would look cleaner to me if you just improve the naming a bit. Also, splitting the huge request into a few functions with smaller responsibility scopes might help.

I would make the endpoint this way:

```
let http = require('http');
let https = require('https');
let Readable = require('stream').Readable;
let router = require('express').Router();
let buffer = [];

/**
 * Gets some data from a remote host. Calls back when done.
 * We cannot pipe this directly into your stream chain as we need the complete data to get the end result.
 */
function getHostname(cb) {

  https.request({

    hostname: 'example.com'
  }, function(response) {

    let data = '';
    response.on('error', err => cb(err)); // shortened for brewity
    response.on('data', function(chunk) {

        data = data + chunk;
    });
    response.on('end', function() {

      // we're done here.
      cb(null, data.toString());
    });
  });
}

router.post('/', function(request, response) {

  // first let's get that url.
  getHostname(function(err, hostname) {

    if (err) { return response.status(500).end(); } 

    // now make that other request which we can stream.
    https.request({

      hostname: hostname,
      method: 'POST'
    }, function(dataStream) {

        dataStream.pipe(response);
    });
  });
});
```

Now, as said in the comments, with streams2, you don't have to manage your streams. With node versions pre 0.10 you have had to listen to 'read', 'data' etc events, with newer node versions, it's handled. Furthermore, you don't even need it here, streams are smart enough to handle backpressure on their own.